# Why are the fglrx drivers not up to date?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, radeon, fglrx

I have a AMD Radeon HD 8750M dedicated graphics card and Ubuntu 14.04, so from Software Updater I installed fglrx-updates, how ever after doing a `dmesg | grep fglrx` I found out that the version is from Mar 12 2014. But on the [official amd](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages) website the latest version is from 5/27/2014. Why is that version not on the ubuntu repos since it  [supports](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx) Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Settings>Software and Updates: there is a setting has something to do with that since the 5/27/2014 drivers are a beta and not a stable release.  However I would not recommend using an unstable release with a Graphics card.  So by your settings, the drivers are up to date.

Comment: Thanks, still can you show me how can I add these beta repos?

Comment: In the section on the AMD website about the beta drivers, there are pretty complete instructions on how to install it.  They do not seem to have PPAs developed for the beta drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misreading the text on the AMD website - the latest official driver there is dated 5/22/14.

The support for UbuntU 14.04 appears in the **Beta** driver (released 5/26/14).  I did try this driver, and it failed for me, but that is beside the point:  it is a beta driver and should probably not be included in the repos until the remaining bugs are worked out.

Comment: Ok, but still the latest stable version is 14.4 but on my system is 13.35.5